# Is it possible to use a quantum algorithm to optimize quantum chips

Tags: optimization

I'm really new to QC, so please excuse if this is a dumb question.

I was looking at the different Qubit configurations/arrangments in chips and was wondering if it is possible to create an algorithm to optimize them. On the most basic level, it's just an optimization problem for finding the arrangment with the lowest rate of error.
Wouldn't this be a prime use case for quantum computing?

Answer (score 2):

Optimization problems that involve "optimizing a layout" are generally quadratic constraint optimization problems, as far as I know, these problems are NP-hard so there wouldn't be any sort of advantage in trying to solve this type of problem on a quantum computer.

Comment: Just to note that there are empirical studies showing that some QUBO problems can be solved faster on QC (e.g. some logistics problems). But still we face similar issues like in case of classical heuritstics (e.g. suboptimal solution).